# CURL PHP Login automatico

Tags: php, libcurl, login

Estou aprimorando uma aplicação que fiz há algum tempo, tento realizar login via CURL, porém não consigo fazer a aplicação funcionar com o cookie coletado durante a login via CURL. Consigo salvar o cookie mas não usá-lo. Não sei se estou errando no meio de logar ou na forma de usar o cookie.
OBS: A aplicação já funciona, se eu logar no site www.comprasnet.gov.br e após logar aperto F12 e pego o cookie via Chrome. Aparentemente ele gera um cookie primário ao logar em https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/seguro/loginPortalFornecedor.asp, ele redireciona para a página https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/intro.htm gerando o primeiro cookie. Após clicar no menu que leva ao link https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar.asp, ele gera os dois cookies que são utilizados.

Código que faz o login:

```
<?php
$cookieold = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'cookieJar.txt';
$cookieactive = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'cookieactive.txt';
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/seguro/loginPortalFornecedor.asp";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "perfil=Fornecedor&txtLogin=seulogin&txtSenha=suasenha&ambiente=Produção");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieold);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

// Define uma nova URL para ser chamada (após o login)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieold);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/intro.htm');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
// Executa a segunda requisição
$content = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieold);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar.asp');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieactive);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
// Executa a terceira requisição
$content2 = curl_exec ($ch);

    if ($output === FALSE) {               // verifica erros no curl
       echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    }

curl_close($ch);
//echo $content2;
?>
```

Código que utilizo atualmente para usar o cookie coletado manualmente:

```
// iniciar sessao
$ch = curl_init();

// opcoes
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar.asp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'ASPSESSIONIDQGAADDTC=DDLGMJABKGCABIKENDGOBLJJ;ASPSESSIONIDQGCADASC=LFFGLJABPEAKKIOLNLLCOFIC');
//executar sessao
$output = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($output === FALSE) {               // verifica erros no curl
       echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    }
$output = strtr($output, $conversao); // função de conversão acentuado/não acentuado
//fechar sessao
curl_close($ch);
```

Alguma luz de como fazer funcionar? Não sou programador, sou um fuçador que gosta de se aventurar =).